# Перенос текста из Label в первом view controller в Text во втором View controller swift

Tags: swift, text, controller, label

Подскажите пожалуйста как перенести из первого `View controllera` - `Label` (название ресторана) во второй `View controller` в `Text`. Должно получиться, что переходя с первой страницы (где указано изображение ресторана и название) на вторую страницу отображалось увеличенное изображение ресторана и на изображении текст названия ресторана. Изображение перенес, а вот название пока не догнал как перенести из `Label` на вторую страницу в Текст .

Comment: Покажите код, как совершаете переход между контроллерами, и как передаете изображение.

Answer (score 0):

Просто берешь переменную:

```
let text = label.text
```

Затем устанавливаешь ее в переменную в контроллере, который будет показан при вызове prepareForSegue:

```
newViewController.restName = text
```

И в viewDidLoad нового контроллера начинаешь работать с переданной переменной:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()
  if let restName = restName {
   operation(name: restName)
  }
}
```